# x is only in globals() or locals() when if statement contains both globals() and locals()

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, global, local

I have a question; I have some code for a thread:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    x = makeThread("Thread 1", thread_function, ThreadKeyArg = "PersonalKey\n")
    xx = makeThread("Thread 2", thread_function, ThreadIDArg = 11111)
    xxx = makeThread("Thread 3", thread_function, ThreadKeyArg = "AnotherPersonalKey\n")
    xxxx = makeThread("Thread 4", thread_function, ThreadIDArg = 1234)
```

then, I ask if x is in `locals()` or `globals()`. If the statement is true, then `print("something")` occurs. Here is that section of code:

```
if x in locals() or globals():
    print("something")
```

This code *does* make the `if` statement true, so it does print the text. However, when I put `if x in locals()` or `if x in globals()`, neither times do they `print("something")`. Now, this **does not** cause me any problems, I am just wondering why this is so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues going on here.

1. `x in locals() or globals()` does not distribute the `in` test to check both dictionaries. It works like `(x in locals()) or globals()`, which, if `globals()` is not empty, will always be truthy. If you want to test membership in each dict, you want `x in locals() or x in globals()`
2. `x in locals()` doesn't do what you want. You probably mean `"x" in locals()`. Otherwise you're testing if the *value* of `x` is also a key in the `locals()` dict (e.g. a variable name). Since the value of `x` is probably some kind of thread object, that's never going to work. Use a string if you want to test for the literal variable name `"x"`.